# ExtJS : button with action to json format

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

**How to create a x-type button with action:**

For creating some widgets in we uses Json file to structure it. 
If I write something like this, sencha ext js works on this json and will generate as I expected.

```
"editViewFields": [
                    {
                        "xtype": "textfield",
                        "name": "text1",
                        "fieldLabel": "Text 1 : "
                    },
                    {
                        "xtype": "button",
                        "text": "name",
                        "width": 75
                    }
                  ]
```

It will generate a text field and button.

Now I want to create button with action as this,

```
 text : 'Button',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            // this == the button, as we are in the local scope
            this.setText('I was clicked!');
        }
    }
```

Some thing Like this I tried but not working:

```
            {
                "xtype": "button",
                "text": "name",
                "width": 75,
                "enableToggle": true,
                "listeners": {
                    "click": {
                        "this.setText": "(I was clicked!)"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please provide all your valuable info regarding this.

Comment: i guess your button gets rendered right? So your listener doesnt work ?!

Comment: Yes, button gets rendered but listeners notworking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using the "handler" config as shown below** (**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/7sts90vu/)**)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var myButton = Ext.create("Ext.button.Button", {
        "text": "name",
        "width": 75,
        "enableToggle": true,
        "handler": function (button, options) {
            button.setText("I was clicked!");        
        },
        "renderTo": Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

So your code would be like,

```
{
    "xtype": "button",
    "text": "name",
    "width": 75,
    "enableToggle": true,
    "handler": function (button, options) {
        button.setText("I was clicked!");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why handler value is not json format, json parsing itself showing error on line: "handler": function (button, options) {
        button.setText("I was clicked!");        
    }

Comment: If you have a controller, then create a function to handle the click event there. Then add a controller level event which in turn calls this click handler. So your handler property will be like "handler":"myClickHandlerFunction"

Comment: No I don't have control over there, I can write only json strings. And  if u ask me then what make me think to add some actions over there is because, they provide some default widgets by many actions in it. But didn't reveal the codes. thanks anyway.

Comment: Another way to add a click handler is to set a unique "id" config to the button (For example: id:"myButtonElementId") and then use pure JS to write a listener for this button. For example, document.getElementById("myButtonElementId").onclick=function(){doSomeAction()};

Answer (score 1):

your listeners config doesnt look right. It should look something like this

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Click me!',                

    listeners: {
        "click": function(btn){
            btn.setText('I was clicked!');
        }
    }        
}
```

Here is a fiddle exmaple: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/97q

Here is also a link to the listeners doc and a other way to configure it http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-listeners

Comment: I don't know why is this answer voted down because it actually DOES answer the question and also demonstrates it at fiddle.

Comment: Hey, its working fine. But, how am I supposed to write function in json string!!!! :/

Comment: What I am trying is through json string create a button with action, In my question in codes section 3rd u can see what I tried, you want me to write "function(btn)" for key "click" in there?

Comment: may i ask why you need these strings?

Comment: Actually i am using it in mozu engine, there new widgets are created through json values of ext js, but didn't created any thing actions. only some text fields and labels are created yet.

You can check the default widgets they were provided her, with many functionalities. http://developer.mozu.com/learn/theme-development/theme-activation/manage-site-pages/default-widgets

Comment: I am trying to create something like that.

PS: By Functionality I means in widget functinoalities.

Comment: sry i dont know mozu - though mby this helps: you cold do something like "click": "btnOnClickFn" in your listeners json obj.. but the btnOnClickFn(){...} must obv exist somewhere.

Comment: Who ever downvoted for this ans I am looking for a valid reason from him, may be help me out!